# Extract the filename from an IOException message

Tags: c#, message, filepath, ioexception

I'd like to know how to extract the file path from an IOException message.

The following code searches subdirectories under `C:\Temp` and detects if any `*_test.xlsx` is being open:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Temp", "*_test.xlsx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        try 
        {
            if (files == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File Not Found");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    using (Stream stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        // Do Nothing
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex); // Here I'd like to show only the 'C:\Temp\3_folder\3_test.xlsx' part
        }
    }
}
```

If the file is being open, an IOException is caught and shows:

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Temp\3_folder\3_test.xlsx' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
   at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
   at CheckIfFileInUse.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\CheckIfFileInUse\Program.cs:line 22
```

However, I don't need the full message.
I only need the file path (In this case, `C:\Temp\3_folder\3_test.xlsx`).

I searched and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417907/extract-class-and-filename-from-exception), but this isn't what I want.
`frame.GetFileName()` of `StackTrace()` returns the program file path (In my case, `C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\CheckIfFileInUse\Program.cs`).

How can I extract the file path from an IOException message?

Comment: In general: you can't, because not every IOException has a file name associated with it. Maybe an EnofOfStreamException (which is an IOException) operates on a MemoryStream, which does not need a file.

Comment: It's not clear why you can't just track this yourself?

Comment: Can't you test for _System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '_ ?

Comment: In this case, I'd argue that you need to move the try/catch inwards anyway, so one file failing won't prevent the rest from being processed. And _then_ you'd already know which file failed.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I see. I don't know much about IOException, but this IOException surely has a file name associated with it (`C:\Temp\3_folder\3_test.xlsx`). Could you tell me how you would handle it?

Comment: @IanHacker see his answer. Consider what you want to do with the rest of the files in the iterated list, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general: you can't, because not every IOException has a file name associated with it. Maybe an EndOfStreamException (which is an IOException) operates on a MemoryStream, which does not need a file.

But it's trivial to build that yourself. Catch the exception on an inner level and throw your own exception instead. Note the `<--` where to make changes

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Temp", "*_test.xlsx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        try 
        {
            if (files == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File Not Found");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    try       // <--
                    {        
                        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
                        {
                            // Do Nothing
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)    // <--
                    {
                        var fileex = new IOExceptionWithFileInfo(file);
                        fileex.InnerException = ex; // Keep the original information
                        throw fileex;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOExceptionWithFileInfo ex)   // <--
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.FileName); 
        }
    }
}
```

TODO for OP as an exercise: implement the class `IOExceptionWithFileInfo`, deriving from `Exception`.

Catching on an inner level can also help you to process all files and build a list of all files that have a problem, like so:

```
var listOfErrors = new List<IOExceptionWithFileInfo>();
[...]
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        var fileex = new IOExceptionWithFileInfo(file);
        fileex.InnerException = ex; // Keep the original information
        listOfErrors.Add(fileex);
    }
[...]
if (listOfErrors.Length > 0)
{
    // Display all of them to the user
}
```

Comment: I would suggest OP include the captured `IOException` as an `InnerException` when rethrowing.

Comment: Note: This will discard process for all files in the list that were to be iterated after the failing one.

Comment: @Fildor: yes, like the original implementation

Comment: Just wanted to be explicit. That _may be_ wanted behavior, though, yes.

Comment: @Llama: yes, I should have done that. Fixed

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thank you. Let me try the exercise. FYI: I'm totally OK to discard the process for all files in the list after failing.

Comment: @Fildor: added a solution for that as well, just for fun.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I've finished the exercise:
    [Serializable]
    internal class IOExceptionWithFileInfo : Exception
    {
        public IOExceptionWithFileInfo(string file) : base(String.Format("File in Use: {0}", file))
        {

        }
    }
... I changed from `ex.Filename` to `ex.Message`, though. Anyway, I learned a lot. Thank you so much!

*Oops, I didn't notice the 'catching on an inner level' extra credit, so this is for next time.

Comment: @IanHacker: Great. Learning is what this site is good for. If you don't need more answers and my answer solved your problem, please tick the checkmark left to the beginning of the answer.